# Can I use \usepackage{showidx} with \showindex \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} in pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, indexing

I'm writing a longer LaTeX report; until recently without hyperref package, but as I feel I want `\nameref`, I also used hyperref.

Unfortunately I am also using `\usepackage{showidx}` as an aid until the index is perfect.
Without `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` the index entries defined are displayed outside the main text at the borders.
However with hyperref the index phrases are displayed inside the main text, making it quite unreadable.

Example (without hyperref):

[image]

Same part with `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}`:

[image]

Is there a way to make showindex work the way it is intended to display?

**Example** (in case you need it):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
%\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\title{Demo}
\author{Me}
\date{11.11.2019}
\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
Dies ist ein Test-Text.\index{Text-|Test}
\end{abstract}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small but complete example, that can be used for tests.

Comment: I always thought people knowing the answer don't need a file to experiment with ;-) OK, I'll add one.

Comment: load showidx after hyperref.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Make it an answer, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load showidx after hyperref (links will perhaps be wrong, but for a draft it shouldn't matter).