# LaTeX: How to define command depending on existence of another command (e.g. `\nameref`)?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'd like to use `\nameref` with `hyperref`, but I want be able to render my document without `hyperref`, too.

So I'd like to define a wrapper command around `nameref` (not defining a "dummy" `\nameref` myself), depending on whether `\nameref` is defined.

The answer preferably works with any defined command, not just `\nameref`.

From similar questions I tried to derive some solution that **did not work**:

```
\newcommand{\checkAndDef}[1]{%
\ifcsname#1\endcsname%
\newcommand{\refn}[1]{\nameref{#1}}%
\else%
\newcommand{\refn}[1]{[#1]}% no \nameref available
\fi%
}
\checkAndDef{nameref}%
```

Note the `\checkAndDef` looks ugly, and I added it after I failed to do a literal check for `\nameref`.  I guess I would need to know more details about TeX and LaTeX to fix that than I do.

**First solution** modeled after werner's proposals (does not work):

```
\newcommand{\namerefcheck}{%
\ifcsname{}nameref\endcsname%
\newcommand{\refn}[1]{\nameref{##1}}%
\else%
\newcommand{\refn}[1]{[\detokenize{##1}]}% no \nameref available
\fi%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\namerefcheck}
```

This "solution" defines `\refn` as if hyperref weren't loaded, regardless whether is is or not.

**Note:** If you replace `{}nameref` with `\nameref`, then it works (it seems to me).

Comment: The package **hyperref** loads the package **[nameref](https://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)** but the package **[nameref](https://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)** can also be loaded without **hyperref**.  If you do that, the command `\nameref` is available without hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here:

1. When defining a command within another command, you need to double up on the use of your parameter notation. So, `#1` should become `##1`, `#2` should become `##2`, and so forth. In that sense, the following definition of `\checkAndDef` is probably what you're after:

   ```
   \newcommand{\checkAndDef}[1]{%
     \ifcsname#1\endcsname%
       \newcommand{\refn}[1]{\nameref{##1}}%
     \else%
       \newcommand{\refn}[1]{[\detokenize{##1}]}% no \nameref available
     \fi%
   }
   ```

   I've added a [`\detokenize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139980/5764) to the "no `\nameref` available" option, since labels can contain some odd characters (like underscore `_`) by default.
2. [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) should usually be loaded last of all the packages, since it interfaces with many document elements, all of which could be changed by other included packages. As such, `\checkAndDef` may be required *after* `\begin{document}` in some cases. This is specifically required for `\nameref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}% Comment out or not

\newcommand{\checkAndDef}[1]{%
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname
    \newcommand{\refn}[1]{\nameref{##1}}%
  \else
    \newcommand{\refn}[1]{[\detokenize{##1}]}% no \nameref available
  \fi
}

\AtBeginDocument{\checkAndDef{nameref}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:section}

\refn{sec:section}

\end{document}
```

The above code results in

[image]

when `hyperref` is loaded, and

[image]

when `hyperref` is *not* loaded.

Comment: On your recommendation that hyperref should be loaded as the last package, please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516039/can-i-use-usepackageshowidx-with-showindex-usepackagepdftexhyperref-in ;-)

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware that `\begin{document}` does some define magic. As the body of `\checkAndDef` only makes sense if the argument is `nameref`, can you simplify that? If the code needs to be run after `\begin{document}` it should be inside a command still, as otherwise it would just look too ugly (IMHO).

Comment: @U.Windl: It's not `\begin{document}` that is doing some magic... it's that some macros are delayed in terms of their definition until `\begin{document}`. So, `\AtBeginDocument{<stuff>}` delays `<stuff>` until after `\begin{document}`. It really depends on what you're defining. You could include the `\AtBeginDocument` as part of the `\checkAndDef` code.

Comment: Also see [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Comment: Would you care to represent an alternate `\AtBeginDocument` version that replaces the first parameter of `\checkAndDef` with literal `nameref`? It seems that would be what I really had in mind.

Comment: @U.Windl: I honestly don't understand your request...

Answer (score 2):

I propose

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\conditionaldef}{mmO{0}omm}
 {% #1 = command to define
  % #2 = command to test
  % #3 = number of args,
  % #4 = default optional
  % #5 = replacement text if #2 exists
  % #6 = replacement text if #2 doesn't exist
  \AtBeginDocument
   {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF #2
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{#4}
       {
        \newcommand{#1}[#3]{#5}
       }
       {
        \newcommand{#1}[#3][#4]{#5}
       }
     }
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{#4}
       {
        \newcommand{#1}[#3]{#6}
       }
       {
        \newcommand{#1}[#3][#4]{#6}
       }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and you call it like

```latex
\conditionaldef{\refn}{\nameref}[1]{\nameref{#1}}{[\detokenize{#1}]}
```

### Full example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\conditionaldef}{mmO{0}omm}
 {% #1 = command to define
  % #2 = command to test
  % #3 = number of args,
  % #4 = default optional
  % #5 = replacement text if #2 exists
  % #6 = replacement text if #2 doesn't exist
  \AtBeginDocument
   {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF #2
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{#4}{\newcommand{#1}[#3]{#5}}}{\newcommand{#1}[#3][#4]{#5}}
     }
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{#4}{\newcommand{#1}[#3]{#6}}{\newcommand{#1}[#3][#4]{#6}}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\conditionaldef{\refn}{\nameref}[1]{\nameref{#1}}{[\detokenize{#1}]}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

\refn{test}

\end{document}
```

### Output if `hyperref` is loaded

[image]

### Output if `hyperref` is not loaded

[image]

### Note

You essentially use the same syntax as for `\newcommand`, so also commands with a single optional argument are allowed. No need of doubling `#` when calling `\conditionaldef`.

### Without `xparse`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% syntax
%% \conditionalref{<marg>}[<oarg>][<oarg>]{<marg>}{<marg>}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conditionaldef}[2]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\cond@def@opt{#1}{#2}}{\cond@def@noopt{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\cond@def@noopt}[4]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifdefined#2%
      \newcommand{#1}{#3}%
    \else
      \newcommand{#1}{#4}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\cond@def@opt#1#2[#3]{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\cond@def@twoopt{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\cond@def@oneopt{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}
\def\cond@def@oneopt#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifdefined#2%
      \newcommand{#1}[#3]{#4}%
    \else
      \newcommand{#1}[#3]{#5}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\cond@def@twoopt#1#2#3[#4]#5#6{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifdefined#2%
      \newcommand{#1}[#3][#4]{#5}%
    \else
      \newcommand{#1}[#3][#4]{#6}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\conditionaldef{\refn}{\nameref}[1]{\nameref{#1}}{[\detokenize{#1}]}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}\label{test}

\refn{test}

\end{document}
```

### Simpler version

Of course, the above is a waste of time if you just want to define *one* command: a simple

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifdefined\nameref
    \newcommand{\refn}[1]{\nameref{#1}}%
  \else
    \newcommand{\refn}[1]{[\detokenize{#1}]}%
  \fi
}
```

will suffice. The infrastructure above allows to define *many* commands without code duplication.

Comment: This answer looks nice, but can it be done without xparse also?

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, certainly. Why?

Comment: Defining many commands creates a "dependency mess", so I prefer solutions with no extra dependencies. Didn't need xparse yet.

Comment: @U.Windl Compare the codes in the updated answer and you'll know why I'd prefer `xparse`.

Comment: OK, as my final solution was based on werner's proposals, I'll accept the latter as an answer. Probably simply, because he was faster.

Comment: @U.Windl I don't mind about the green tick. Anyway, why bother with defining \checkRef` if you just want to cope with *one* command? See final note in the edited answer.

Comment: Actually it's two commands I'm defining, but both depend on `\nameref`. Anyway I think your answer is valuable for other people that have a similar problem. Votes will tell ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the token `\BizArReUnDEFiNeD` is always undefined, you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% \checkAndDef{<other command>}%
%             {<definition-command><new command><parameter text>}%
%             {<new command's definition-text in case other command is undefined>}%
%             {<new command's definition-text in case other command is defined>}
%
% <parameter text> can be omitted.
%
\newcommand\checkAndDef[4]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \ifx\BizArReUnDEFiNeD#1%
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {#2{#3}}{#2{#4}}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
%\csname @ifpackageloaded\endcsname{hyperref}{}{\usepackage{nameref}}

\checkAndDef{\nameref}{\newcommand*\refn[1]}{\detokenize{[#1]}}{\nameref{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\section{Test-Section}\label{test}%
Some text. Reference: \refn{test}
\end{document}
```